# Download video from Uri in android

Tags: android, uri

I have searched a lot about this but i am not getting the exact answer.

Is there any way to download video to sd card from any **Uri**.
I am not sure whether it is a valid question or not, if not then i am sorry.

can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One would normally download from a server.

Comment: can you please explain me

Comment: Well actually i asked explanation from you. So go ahead.

Comment: Download from `URI` doesn't really make sense which is why you probably didn't get exact answers before.. Read up on what  `URI` is first. What you need is a `URL` which is a subset of `URI`

Comment: why dont you convert URI to URL and download video?

Comment: @Redman  Actually i want to download video from youtube.
But in Youtube Api this offline video functionality is not there.
so i am using **com.github.Commit451.YouTubeExtractor:youtubeextractor:2.1.0** this library which will take one youtube **video ID** (ex- [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-igAiudpBng) for this video ,id is -igAiudpBng) and convert in into an **Uri**.

So i want to download that video from the Uri

Comment: @greenapps Actually i want to download video from youtube. But in Youtube Api this offline video functionality is not there. so i am using **com.github.Commit451.YouTubeExtractor:youtubeextractor:2.1.0** this library which will take one youtube **video ID** (ex- link for this video ,id is -igAiudpBng) and convert in into an **Uri**. So i want to download that video from the Uri

Comment: You still keep saying that you want to download from an uri. And are not reacting on that you should download from a server or that you need an url. I wonder why you dont understand that you have to tell us how the uri looks like. Whats in the uri? Where does it point to?

Comment: @greenapps what is wrong with saying "Thanks in advance"

Comment: I told you already. That you will not say thank you after you have been helped.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133962/discussion-between-ananya-and-greenapps).